# Using VBControlExtender with manifest results in error 438 (doesn't support this property or method)?

Tags: vb6, manifest

I use vb6 dll/ocx without registration, using manifest file. 90% of application working ok, but one part who using `VBControlExtender` not working.

```
Dim oRegion as VBControlExtender  
Set oRegion.Properties = Prop
```

Error: 438  object doesn't support this property or method

If register ocx then working ok!?

manifest file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<file name="Dll\XMLKontrolaNalaz.ocx">
   <typelib tlbid="{AFC41DA0-934F-46CB-9421-B0798C427C74}" version="1.0" flags="" helpdir="" />
   <comClass clsid="{4437736B-A865-446B-B6E4-924EBC9197A5}" 
             tlbid="{AFC41DA0-934F-46CB-9421-B0798C427C74}" 
             threadingModel="Apartment" progid="XMLKontrolaNalaz.ucTxt" />
   <comClass clsid="{37AB7E7A-C924-47C0-BA6F-05C9586D4AE4}" 
             tlbid="{AFC41DA0-934F-46CB-9421-B0798C427C74}" 
             threadingModel="Apartment" progid="XMLKontrolaNalaz.ucOpt" />
...
```

Comment: Can you show the portion of your manifest which includes the OCX you are referring to? And which OCX are you referring to?

Comment: One possibility is that you are accessing two different versions of that OCX - the manifested file could be old / incorrect but the registered copy could be correct.

Comment: Edit it into the question - its unreadable as a comment

Comment: Done. Look the question

Comment: So... is `prop` in your code sample an object from XMLKontrolaNalaz.ocx?

Comment: Prop is object Properties who set on oRegion.Properties

Comment: Problem is then who not view Properies property on VBControlExtender

Comment: Sorry but I had a hard time understanding your last comments. Could you try to explain it another way?